# How to get creator information about particular resource from kubectl get or describe command

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know who create pod from kubectl get or describe command.
Can I insert this field into Pod? or Custom Resource Definition?
Please help.

when I access to kubernetes cluster as user 'Alice' and create pod 'sample-pod'
I want to see as follows when exec 'kubectl get pod sample-pod' command.

```
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    CREATEUSER
sample-pod   1/1     Running   0          10s    Alice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the information about authenticated Kubernetes users is not included in the general API reference list for [Pod core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#pod-v1-core) schema objects. Therefore, it's not possible to retrieve user data from Pod specification. Actually, you might try to use [Service accounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) that granted to manage Kubernetes API via [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) mechanism, in that way you can create a particular SA in namespace related to a specific user, and use it for any resource Kubernetes creation purpose. Although the information about SA name for specific resource propagated through `.spec.serviceAccountName` field in relevant object configuration template, you can invoke it using `custom-columns=` option in `kubectl get` command:

`kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNT:.spec.serviceAccountName`

Comment: I understand. It's very helpful! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you found that the answer was valuable for you, please evaluate it for any further contributors research.

Answer (score 0):

kubectl get pods  -n  -o yaml will give the pod definition. you can edit and use it for deploying pods.

Comment: when I access to kubernetes cluster as user 'Alice' and create pod 'sample-pod' I want to see like NAME sample-pod READY 1/1 STATUS Running RESTARTS 0 AGE 10s CREATE USER Alice